fontspec and custom class triggers The font size \normalsize is not defined
I'm trying to create class based on beamer to make presentations as simple as possible while following the graphic manual we have.
I need to use fontspec and I'm using luaLaTeX package to load OTF fonts Roboto and Montserrat.
I got an error message about \normalsize not defined. By meddling I mean adding code to myclass.cls only.
I've removed all I could to this extent:
myclass.cls:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2024/07/31 customized presentation LaTeX class]
%\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\LoadClass{beamer}

test.tex:
\documentclass{myclass}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 Foo Bar
\end{frame}
\end{document}

When I use \Requirepackage{fontspec} I get in TeXmaker error line:
File: /MikTeX-root/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Type: Error
Line: 439
Message: ! LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:there is probably something wrong with the class file. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help.

The snippet in the log file:
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/username/AppData
/Local/MiKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
! LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:
there is probably something wrong with the class file.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.439 ...if_in:NnT \@filelist {.cls} { \normalsize }
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
(C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(C:/MiKTeX/tex/latex/luatex85/luatex85.sty
Package: luatex85 2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
)

When I use \usepackage{fontspec} in text.tex instead the file compiles without any error message.
I have built another article-based class that uses fontspec too and \RequirePackage{fontspec} works fine with lualaTeX.

Clean-up completed

fontspec checks if \normalsize is defined. If you load it before the class, it isn't yet defined.
Load the fontspec package after the class instead:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2024/07/31 customized presentation LaTeX class]
\LoadClass{beamer}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


So the problem was the other class is for my use only, so it can be messy to some extent. I tried to polish the beamer-based class to be more readable. Not a good idea.
